# How to multi update fields on a table excluding non existent ones

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I made a query that takes a count of rows in `tableA` and groups the count by a `set_id` field into a temporary table `c`. It then does an `UPDATE` on `tableB` by changing the values of its `current_count` field to the values from table `c`'s  `count` if the `count` field from table `c` has the same `set_id` as the `current_count` field's `set_id` value.

```sql
UPDATE sets, (
  SELECT
    set_id, 
    COUNT(set_id) AS count
  FROM leads_auto
  GROUP BY set_id
) c 
SET sets.current_count = c.count
WHERE sets.set_id = c.set_id
```

The shortcoming of this query is that it cannot `UPDATE` `tableB` with a `current_count` value of zero if the **no count exists** in table `c` for `tableB`'s `set_id`.

I tried this

```sql
UPDATE sets, (
  SELECT
    set_id,
    COUNT(set_id) AS count
  FROM leads_auto
  GROUP BY set_id
) d
SET sets.current_count = 0 
WHERE sets.set_id != d.set_id
```

But it **does not effect any rows** on `tableB` even though table `c` returns rows with a `set_id` in `tableB` and excludes some `set_id`'s that do exist in `tableB`.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

```sql
SELECT set_id, COUNT(set_id) AS count FROM leads_auto GROUP BY set_id
```

**Returns**

```
set_id |   count
-------+---------
     1 |       7
     5 |       5
     4 |      16
     7 | 2000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is effectively an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
WHERE sets.set_id = c.set_id
```

It returns only rows that exist in both tables.  Convert the query to a `LEFT JOIN` to return `NULL` values for the right-hand table when no match is found:

```sql
UPDATE sets AS s
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
   set_id,
   COUNT(set_id) as cnt 
  FROM leads_auto 
  GROUP BY set_id
) d
ON s.set_id = d.set_id
SET s.current_count = COALESCE(d.cnt, 0)
```

- [Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc17f/1/0)

Comment: I get an `Error #1064`. Good use of `coalesce` though.

Comment: 1064 might mean you can't use `count` as a column alias?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from sets as s left join ( select set_id , c' at line 1`

I used `cnt`. I always thought `UPDATE` has to have the form of `UPDATE [tablename]`?

Comment: Okay so removing the `from` and the `as` from `as d` does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: The `as d` part should be fine, see also the SQL Fiddle example.